# How should I use a library of classes I made in Xcode for an iPhone application?

Tags: xcode, build, target, workspace

I wrote a set of objective c classes, which I now plan on using in a project of mine. My old way would be to copy-paste them in, but that's sloppy, especially now that Xcode has got me using unit tests and code repositories.

I'm thinking what I need is maybe to #include the library from its current location by path maybe, or add a target or a workspace or something, I just don't understand Xcode well enough to know how all this works. The outcome I'd like is for my existing classes to stay synchronized with the project they are in, and not be copied separately, so I can open that project, make changes, build and unit test, and otherwise not alter that library.

Can someone point my in the right direction here? Sorry if this is confusing, I don't know enough about it to really know what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would create a static library for the shared sources (which may have its own repo), then link that to your app. it's best to configure the library in an external project, configure the static library target as a dependency to the app. naturally, you'll have to add the static lib's source directory to your app target's header search paths.

Answer (score 1):

If all your code is in the same repository, then multiple projects can use the same source code. No need to create a library.

Comment: Xcode set up a repository for me for that project where I created and tested these files. I'd like to have these classes "stand alone" somehow, they'll be used in another project later.

Comment: Xcode will create a git repository for you, but if you have multiple projects that share the same code, you may want to put everything into one repository. You'll want to create and manage the repository yourself. An alternative would be multiple repositories, but where you pull from multiple repositories for one project.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Xcode is pretty good at managing multiple repositories.

### The steps I used:

- Create a new project with its own GIT repository,
- Create a new workspace.
- Drag both projects into that workspace.
- Drag the files meant to be reused into the new project, choosing not to copy files.
- That's it, you can now run unit tests from the original project, make changes, etc, and updates will be reflected in the other project

---

Worth mentioning that making the combined workspace might not even be necessary.